# Bug DBGp Response Error: error code 206

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I have used Xdebug of Eclipse 3 months so far. And it runs really well.

However, I got a issue of Xdebug which is "DBGp Response Error: eval:=206 msg:error evaluating code" ( in Error Log).

After I investigate the error, I find that issue is:

> 206 - Error evaluating code (use from eval() (or perhaps property_get
>   for a full name get))"

This is reference from http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php

I have taken 2 days for this issue, and nothing has changed.

Please help me solve this. Many thanks and strong appreciation for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting your watches. You can read the story of how this [worked for me](http://rocinantesoftware.blogspot.com.es/2017/01/phpstorm-xdebug-error-code-206.html) in PHPStorm.

Comment: zomg. saved my life!! this was my exact issue. I would have never figured this out.

Comment: When you are at a dinner party sometime and someone asks you if you have ever saved a life, you can say, "Yes, yes, I have. Two of them."

Comment: Three of them, @Hans !! Thank you very much Ed!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an eval that (your IDE) is doing wrong. Either the symbol does not exist, or the syntax is incorrect. I am not sure where your error_log comes from (do you mean xdebug.remote_log?), but that will also indicate what eval command was sent by the IDE. If you could amend your question with the *exact* log lines before and after your 206 error too, I can give a better clue. In general, this isn't much of an issue, as it's often not possible to eval specific code.

Comment: In fact, the message " 206 - Error evaluating code (use from eval() (or perhaps property_get for a full name get))" appears at the first line ( default index.php of framework which is : $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';).
This log is in Error log of Eclipse. The strange in here is that it has run well, and suddenly can not debug with those things in error log.

Comment: I have taken 2 days to solve it. And the working solution is to upgrade php to 5.5 and change XAMPP 1.7.3 ( which use php 5.3) to MAMP 2.0 ( which use php 5.5). Everything is good now. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

CentOS 7.7
PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.4
Apache and cli

Same symptoms  " The strange in here is that it has run well, and suddenly can not debug with those things in error log" as @ndnguyen

Worked great. Then suddenly didn't work without explanation.  I tried updating everything, several different config options, etc, etc.

Just that stupid little check box.  FYI: The IDE is vscode.